# Why is just this one field of a Hibernate controlled object/entity not being created or updated?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have an object "Chemical" that is updated according to entries in an HTML page.  The data is returned to the Java code correctly, yet this one field is not updating or being created in the database. The chemical entity is defined as follows:

```
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name="Chemical.findAll", query="SELECT c FROM Chemical c")
public class Chemical implements Serializable {
  @Id
  @Column(name="chemical_id")
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private int chemicalId;

...
  private string formula; <---  THE FIELD THAT WILL NOT UPDATE/BE CREATED

....

 public void setFormula(String formula) {
   this.formula = formula;
}

public String getFormula() {
   return this.formula;
}

.....
```

The Java code that actually saves/updates the database:

```
public void saveOrUpdate(final T data) throws CPDPersistenceException {
    final EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
    try {
    final EntityTransaction transaction = em.getTransaction();
    transaction.begin();
    em.merge(data);
    transaction.commit();
} catch (final PersistenceException e) {
    throw new PersistenceException(e);
}
}
```

After the code is executed, other fields have changed in the database if changes have been made. However, "formula" is not changed and remains a NULL field. Can anybody see why?

Comment: You need to add `@Column(name="formula")` above the variable.

Comment: I'll try that, but there are a bunch of other fields that are being populated correctly that do not have the @Column(name = WHATEVER) line above them.

Comment: Nope, you don't need to define the `@Column` on a field ... JPA defines defaults (read the JPA spec if not believing me). `@Basic` is the most that could be needed but most JPA providers don't require that since String is a supported type

Comment: Also your post doesnt say whether the object is already persistent, whether you created the schema before adding that field, what the schema is, what SQL is invoked when you invoke a JPA operation. All of this is basic info for debugging

Answer (score 0):

There is I think a difference between UPDATE and CREATE.

Try to replace em.merge(data) with em.persist(data)

Does it save the content the first time you create a new row with persist ?
What is the length of your string definition in the database ?
Check the database logs whenever the HQL is run from your code, do the log complain at one point during the persist ?

It might be necessary to first test if the row exists before you can run a merge.